# Compilation error start up failed Invalid command line for usage of javac

Tags: grails-2.2

I am new to grails I first Installed Java 1.7 then I set path `JAVA_HOME` to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
```

and `GRAILS_HOME` to

```
D:\grails\grails-2.2.4
```

and I set path to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;D:\grails\grails-2.2.4\bin
```

and I am compiling the application from command prompt ,when I run the application using

```
grails RunApp
```

I got the following error

```
grails 2.2.4 error compilation error start up failed Invalid commandline for usage of javac.    
JavaC:invalid flag: Xlint :-option.
```

Will this version support tomcat 7.0 for deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails 2.2 support java 1.7 which you are doing is correct and this version supports tomcat 7.0. I tried grails 2.2 with java 1.6 and run my applications successfully so can try it with java6 so that you can run your applications.